# Cannot set property 'display' of undefined js

Tags: javascript, onclick, display

Some errors about `onclick` event

The following is part of my code :

```js
var srcElement = null;
        var valueElement = null;
        showTree = function (item, valueId) {
            srcElement = window.event.srcElement;
            valueElement = document.getElementById(valueId);
            var x = getLeft(item);
            var y = getTop(item) + item.offsetHeight;
            var w = item.offsetWidth;
            blockDTree(x, y, w);
        }
        getTop = function (e) {
            var offset = e.offsetTop;
            if (e.offsetParent != null) offset += getTop(e.offsetParent);
            return offset;
        }
        getLeft = function (e) {
            var offset = e.offsetLeft;
            if (e.offsetParent != null) offset += getLeft(e.offsetParent);
            return offset;
        }

        blockDTree = function (x, y, w) {

            var item = $("#combdtree");
            item.style.display = 'block';
            item.style.top = y;
            item.style.left = x;
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" class="FormStyle2" onClick='showTree(this,"pid")' readonly="readonly" placeholder="父节点"/>       
<div id="combdtree" class="dtreecob" ></div>
<div class="dtree" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

however,when i run it,i meet with:

```
Home:725 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

at blockDTree (Home:725)
at showTree (Home:709)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Home:63)
```

What's wrong with the code ?It confused me for two days.How to solve it?

Comment: Your sample code is not correctly formatted at all.Can you paste real formatted code please?

Comment: It is because of `var item = $("#combdtree");`  apply `var item = document.getElementById("combdtree");` there to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned a jQuery Object to **item**

```
blockDTree = function(x, y, w) {
        var item = $("#combdtree");      // this is a jQuery object
        item.style.display = 'block';    // this does not work because jQuery do not have variable or method called style
}
```

So jQuery trying to find a method or variable called style, which is not defined, change your code to use Javascript

Your code will become

```
 blockDTree = function(x, y, w) {
        var item = document.getElementById("combdtree");
        item.style.display = 'block';
        item.style.top = y;
        item.style.left = x;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`item` is a jQuery object, not an element

Solution 1: using the element

```
blockDTree = function(x, y, w) {
    var item = $("#combdtree")[0];    // now item is the first such element and since ID's are unique, there's no issue assuming there's only one

    item.style.display = 'block';
    item.style.top = y;
    item.style.left = x;
}
```

Solution 2: using jQuery

```
blockDTree = function(x, y, w) {
    var item = $("#combdtree");
    item.css({display:'block', top:x, left:x});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Solution :
>
> 1. You are not using jquery, so don't use `$("#combdtree");`
> 2. Apply `var item = document.getElementById("combdtree");`

Please check below code :

```js
var srcElement = null;
var valueElement = null;
showTree = function (item, valueId) {
    srcElement = window.event.srcElement;
    valueElement = document.getElementById(valueId);
    var x = getLeft(item);
    var y = getTop(item) + item.offsetHeight;
    var w = item.offsetWidth;
    blockDTree(x, y, w);
}
getTop = function (e) {
    var offset = e.offsetTop;
    if (e.offsetParent != null) offset += getTop(e.offsetParent);
    return offset;
}
getLeft = function (e) {
    var offset = e.offsetLeft;
    if (e.offsetParent != null) offset += getLeft(e.offsetParent);
    return offset;
}

blockDTree = function (x, y, w) {
    var item = document.getElementById("combdtree");
    if (item != null) {
        item.style.display = 'block';
        item.style.top = y;
        item.style.left = x;
    }
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="FormStyle2" onClick='showTree(this,"pid")' readonly="readonly" placeholder="父节点" />
<div id="combdtree" class="dtreecob"></div>
<div class="dtree" style="overflow:auto;width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: this simple answer really helped me which figuring out why document.getElementById("#combdtree") is not working, i'm using react & nextjs nowadays so this really made my day. thankyou!